# What is a safe, reliable site to make a calendar without losing control of photos or privacy issues?

Tags: printing, privacy, gifts

I would like to make a calendar for my mom using photos of her grandchildren. I was planning to use Shutterfly until it came to my attention that that site retains copies of your photos on an "internal system" even after you have deleted them.  I would like to find a site or service that will completely delete upload photos from their system after you have finished making the product and have chosen to delete.  Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Hi Jennifer, Welcome to photo.stackexchange. Can I ask you to "edit-in" how this issue came to your attention? More detail might help with a better answer.

Comment: @Stan, what does it matter? She obviously doesn't agree to ToS, simple as that. It's not relevant to the question at all.

Comment: @Stan, the issue of privacy actually came to my attention through this very forum site.  https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/91541/does-shutterfly-com-own-my-photos-even-after-i-deleted-them  I then called Shutterfly's 1-888 number and got a similar answer from their customer service rep as the one in the customer services response in the link above.

Comment: Do you use a computer? If so, what OS are you using (Windows, Mac, ...)? There are several applications available to help you create and order photo calendars.

Comment: Adding those details into the question turns your "source" from a rumour into a more factual means to verify any site's policy. Shutterfly is the specific example in this case of yours of who to ask. I was appealing for a "better" question with detail that others can understand and benefit without having to read comments.

Comment: You *cannot* ever know if the files will be deleted completely.  As a matter of common sense a company should retain a copy as sometimes people sue or make claims against them for various reasons - they need to keep the files for a some time in case they have to prove something abut the material they received.  I'd be surprised if any company would truly erase files on demand for that reason.

Comment: Just go to a local copy shop. The bigger ones can print you anything and make a nice calendar from it. Since they are local buisnesses, i would trust them the most of all options.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is not exactly of what you want but replying in regard to privacy, as you are concerned about it.

You have come to know about Shutterfly that they save the images but you cannot be sure about other sites as well for the following reasons.

1. Somewhere you may get a suggestion about another site that doesn't save but later you may get to know that they save.
2. It can also happen that the site doesn't save but the site Moderators may have an access for some time. I have a site and I'm well experienced with it. This even ruins the site reputation.
3. It may also happen that the site's security has been breached.

If you search for some of the recent privacy breaches you will get a good idea of what I mean.

IMO it will be best if you can make the calendar on your own or ask someone you know to make one for you.

There are several formats available on the net, download them & use in any photo editing software. This will also add an extra love & affection in you work.

Comment: ...And then you'd have to print and collate them, which is normally difficult if you don't have the equipment. So back to the starting point: you'd have to bring the calendar file to a photographer...

Answer (score -1):

Free advice is worth *every penny* you *paid* for it.

With that understood, here's some advice:

1. Trust everyone; but, cut the cards.
2. There are no guarantees in life
3. Contact any service that you locate with a Web search or from a personal recommendation directly. Ask them for their current End-User Service Agreement or End-User Licensing Agreement which will stipulate *all* of the situations **that favour them, not you**. When you get it, carefully read the terms and conditions of the agreement. Do not trust what is told to you by any third party notwithstanding your legal counsel.